# Как правильно: жвачка или жевачка?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: жвачка или жевачка?

Контекст: применительно к жевательной резинке.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Все словари кроме БТС Кузнецова дают только один вариант - жвачка.
Рекомендую все же именно его.

Comment: Словарь синонимов ASIS - жевачка, жвачка.
Толковый словарь Ожегова - жевачка, жвачка.
БТС Кузнецова (современный рус.яз.) - жевачка, жвачка. 
А что, БТС Кузнецова не авторитет? Почему тогда на портале "Грамота.ру", финансовую поддержку  которого осуществляет Федеральное агентство по печати и массовым коммуникациям,именно он представлен универсальным справочником по современному русскому языку, а не др. авторы толковых словарей? Получается, что этот словарь лучше, а доверия меньше. Парадокс!

Comment: У Ожегова есть жевачка???
Это меняет дело.

Касательно "парадокса". Кузнецов действительно не авторитет. Не хочу сейчас по новой гнать волну на его весьма вольное обращение с толкованием слов, но, простите, орфография и орфоэпия - это вообще не его область. У меня встречный вопрос. Зачем тогда издавать столько разнонаправленных словарей, если каждый - авторитет во всех областях русского языка?  
"Поддержка" не гарантирует ничего кроме весьма нерегулярной подпитки портала и права иметь процитированную Вами гордую надпись. А словари берутся тех авторов, которые делятся копирайтами.

Comment: У Ожегова - только жвачка. Жевачка - это уже от Шведовой.

Comment: С. И. Ожегов "Словарь русского языка",-М."Советская энциклопедия", с.175 - "жвачка" и никак иначе.

Answer (score 6):

До жевательной резинки была жвачка - медленно пережёвываемая пища (и  жвачные животные).

Все произносили грамотно - жвачка.

Потом появилась жевательная резинка. Её  стали называть сокращённо жевачкой, в таком виде слово есть у Ожегова и Шведовой.

[ЖЕВАЧКА](http://ozhegov.info/slovar/?ex=Y&q=%D0%96%D0%95%D0%92%D0%90%D0%A7%D0%9A%D0%90).
(Они говорят, что "жвачка" - разговорное детское).
Но поскольку уже было "правильное литературное" слово *жвачка* примерно про то же самое, то все словари стали настаивать на существовании только одного "правильного" варианта, а другой вариант если и признают, то считают разговорным. Думаю, в этом есть свой резон. К тому же это оправдывается и тем, что некоторые современные слова при образовании похожих словоформ повторяют редукцию гласных по аналогии с падением редуцированных.

Answer (score 1):

Материал из Википедии — свободной энциклопедии:
Жва́чка — пережёвывание отрыгнутой пищи, свойственное жвачным животным, также сама эта пища.
Жвачка — разговорное название жевательной резинки.
Жвачка для рук — пластичная игрушка.

Answer (score 0):

Кто бы что ни говорил, но ЖВАЧКА - это то, что жуют жвачные животные. А ЖЕВАЧКА - это сокращенное название жевательной резинки. Два разных слова. Жевательная резинка не является  медленно пережевываемой пищей. Она вообще не пища. Учитывая тот процесс, который происходит у животных, слово ЖВАЧКА, применительно к людям, просто режет слух. Даже представить жутко.